# Finding Max element of the list of lists in c++ (conversion of python function)

Tags: c++, python-3.x

I wanted to convert the following function python to c++:

```
def find_max_value(list):
max_value_list = []
for i in list:
    max_value_list.append(i[0])
return max(max_value_list)
```

The inputs are the : [[90.272948, 210.999601, 90.31622, 349.000214, 4.042645], [520.293431, 349.000041, 520.285479, 211.000041, 2.007837], [237.026305, 263.076182, 237.629826, 247.023679, 4.523158]]

The Output is 520.293431.

I have tried but getting some errors. Could you please mention where I'm doing wrong?

```
std::list<int> find_max_value(std::list<int> a(std::list<double> b)){
std::list<int> max_value_list; 
for (std::list<int>::iterator i = *a.begin(); i!=*a.end(); ++i){
    max_value_list.push_back(i.front());
    return std::max_element(i);
}
}
```

Those are the errors:
[image]

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: `std::list<int> a(std::list<double> b)` declares `a` to be a function that returns `list<int>` and takes `list<double>` as a parameter. I don't think that's what you meant, but I'm not sure what it is you meant. Also, the C++ version of `find_max_value` is declared to return a list, while the Python version returns a single value.

Comment: *Could you please mention where I'm doing wrong?* -- In general, what you're doing wrong is not actually learning the C++ language properly, and attempting to do a line-by-line translation from Python to C++.  This type of "translation" almost always fails.  The way to properly translate languages is to know language A and language B well enough, see what language A is doing, throw language A away, and implement the solution in language B using language B's idioms.

Comment: okay. thanks. I know python but it is needed to convert into c++. So I was trying. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @shakhawat C++ is one of the most complex languages out there.  You can't simply take something written in Python, Java, C#, pick your language, and blindly attempt to "translate" it to C++ without proper knowledge of C++.  For example, you pass the `list` by value, because that's what it looks like in Python.  A C++ programmer would never do this for the purpose you are seeking -- instead they would know to pass the `list` by reference (or const reference).  All of these fundamental details are missed when you don't know C++ properly.

Comment: You'll need to start by deciding what type your `list` is supposed to be. In contrast to Python you need to determine this up-front. You cannot for example mix `int`s and `double`s in containers. It is also unusual to use lists. Vectors are usually a better choice.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie : Yeah got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess you are looking for something like this:

```
double find_max_value(const std::list<std::list<double>>& a){
  return std::max_element(a.begin(), a.end(),
    [](const std::list<double>& lhs, const std::list<double>& rhs) {
      return lhs.front() < rhs.front();
    }
  )->front();
}
```

This assumes none of the lists involved are empty.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Note: This finds the max element in a list of lists as the title asked for. The python code however finds the max element of the first elements in the inner lists - which is what [Igor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71012468/7582247) does.</sup>

You need a 2D `std::list` in order for your data to be stored in a similar way as in the python code. You can then use [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) on all the inner lists.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <list>

double find_max_value(const std::list<std::list<double>>& list) {
    // start with the lowest possible double
    double result = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest();

    for (auto& inner : list) {
        if (!inner.empty())
            result = std::max(result, *std::max_element(inner.begin(), inner.end()));
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::list<std::list<double>> list{
        {90.272948, 210.999601, 90.31622, 349.000214, 4.042645},
        {520.293431, 349.000041, 520.285479, 211.000041, 2.007837},
        {237.026305, 263.076182, 237.629826, 247.023679, 4.523158}};

    std::cout << find_max_value(list) << '\n';
}
```

Output

```
520.293
```

Comment: This is not what the original code does. The original code finds the maximum of the first elements.

Comment: @user17732522 Oh, I didn't read the python code properly and just read _"Finding Max element of the list of lists"_. shakhawat: Please accept Igors answer instead if you want the max value of the first elements.